# What will happen to CircularProgressIndicator Widget after the FutureBuilder has done waiting for the result?

Tags: flutter, future, builder

FutureBuilder examples in Flutter where it return a widget called CircularProgressIndicator or any other widget that acts as a placeholder during the waiting time of asynchronous call. I was wondering, what will happen to the CircularProgressIndicator widget after the FutureBuilder is done with it's async and "replaced" with another widget. Is it going to be disposed or destroyed?

Here's an example.

```
 FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _value,
    builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot,
    ) {
      print(snapshot.connectionState);
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return const Text('Empty data');
        }
      } else {
        return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
      }
    },
  )
```

I just want to check the status of that placeholder widget.

Comment: Can you print snapshot.data inside futurebuilder?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it's just a string from a text file maybe, was it necessary to know? I mean, the future builder returns a Widget, and that widget are being rendered with or without the use of the data from snapshot.